# Programmatically Adding new attribute for existing class property with Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I am trying programmatically add new attribute on top of a class member ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test11
{

public class SomeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SomeAttribute(string value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}


// for attribute to be injected the property should be "virtual"
public class ClassA
{
    public virtual int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Func()
    {

        var type = typeof(ClassA);

        var aName = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
        var ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name);
        var tb = mb.DefineType(type.Name + "Proxy", System.Reflection.TypeAttributes.Public, type);

        var attrCtorParams = new Type[] { typeof(string) };
        var attrCtorInfo = typeof(SomeAttribute).GetConstructor(attrCtorParams);
        var attrBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(attrCtorInfo, new object[] { "Some Value" });
        tb.SetCustomAttribute(attrBuilder);




        PropertyInfo info = typeof(ClassA).GetProperty("Value", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        PropertyBuilder newProp = tb.DefineProperty(info.Name, PropertyAttributes.None, info.PropertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);

        newProp.SetCustomAttribute(attrBuilder);


        //var tbValue = mb.DefineType(info.Name, System.Reflection.TypeAttributes.Public, type);

        FieldBuilder ValueField = tb.DefineField("_Value", typeof(string), FieldAttributes.Private);
        MethodAttributes GetSetAttributes = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Virtual;
        MethodBuilder ValuePropertyGet = tb.DefineMethod("get_Value", GetSetAttributes, typeof(string), Type.EmptyTypes);
        ILGenerator Generator = ValuePropertyGet.GetILGenerator();
        Generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        Generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, ValueField);
        Generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        MethodBuilder ValuePropertySet = tb.DefineMethod("set_Value", GetSetAttributes, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        Generator = ValuePropertySet.GetILGenerator();
        Generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        Generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        Generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, ValueField);
        Generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);


        newProp.SetSetMethod(ValuePropertySet);
        newProp.SetGetMethod(ValuePropertyGet);

        var newType = tb.CreateType();
        var instance = (ClassA)Activator.CreateInstance(newType);

        var attr = (SomeAttribute)instance.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SomeAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault();

        var attr1 = (SomeAttribute)instance.Value.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SomeAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault();

    }
}
}
```

This code created a proxy class for the original class. 
It can easily assign attribute for the entire class.

For a class property, I can replace a property with new getter and setter, assign new attribute, but my call for property GetCustomAttribute returns always NULL

Comment: Why do you want to create an attribute dynamically? If you explain what you *really* want to do, maybe we can find other ways.

Comment: I need to have configurable parameters for my attribute

Comment: Can you explain it more?

Comment: I understand there should be other ways of providing parameters inside of my attribute such as DI or configuration. some of them will not work as this code should be shared between Full framework and .NET Core .
My idea is to create SomeAttribute("My Path") and attached to a ClassA.Value at the boot time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
var attr1 = (SomeAttribute)instance.Value.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SomeAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault();
```

Is looking for the SomeAttribute attribute on the type of Value (an int), not the new Property.

Essentially, you are doing

```
typeof(int).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SomeAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault();
```

Which will, for obvious reasons, return null.

It should be:

```
var attr1 = (SomeAttribute)instance.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(instance.Value), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SomeAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: It's hard to be accurate when you realize you are racing Marc Gravell....

Comment: additional note: because of the property re-definition, the `GetProperty()` is ambiguous; I had to add `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` to make it work