# Copy Attributes of one property to another instead of writing them again

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a model with all the essential validation attributes and data annotations
but I am facing a problem as I can't use this class as a form model as it has extra attributes and I need the form object as small as possible because i am sending its serialized json to an API.
I can approach that "which already did" by copying only the needed properties and their attributes to the other class and I shouldn't worry about keeping the values the same because they will share the same constants but this can backfire if I decided to remove or add attributes. I have to go to each form model and add/remove the attributes
Is there some built-in attribute that clones all the attributes of a given property? like in the next example ?

## Attribute Class

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ClonePropertyAttributesAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ClonePropertyAttributesFromAttribute(Type TargetType,String PropertyName)
    {
         //clone attributes logic here
    }
}
```

## Form Model

```
 public class SignUpFormModel
 {
    [ClonePropertyAttributesFrom(typeof(User),"Email")]
    public String Email { get; set; }
    [ClonePropertyAttributesFrom(typeof(User),"Username ")]
    public String Username { get; set; }
    [ClonePropertyAttributesFrom(typeof(User),"Password")]
    public String Password { get; set; }
    [ClonePropertyAttributesFrom(typeof(User),"First_Name ")]
    public String First_Name { get; set; }
    [ClonePropertyAttributesFrom(typeof(User),"Last_Name")]
    public String Last_Name { get; set; }
    [ClonePropertyAttributes(AttributeProvider(typeof(User).GetProperty("Profile_Picture")))]
    public String Profile_Picture { get; set; }
 }
```

## Model

```
public class User
{
    //### Constansts Definitions ###//
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = EMAIL_DISPLAY_NAME)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = EMAIL_REQUIRED_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [StringLength(EMAIL_MAX_LENGTH, ErrorMessage = EMAIL_LENGTH_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [RegularExpression(EMAIL_REGEX, ErrorMessage = EMAIL_REGEX_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [Remote(EMAIL_REMOTE_DOES_EXIST_ACTION_NAME, EMAIL_REMOTE_EXIST_CONTROLLER_NAME, ErrorMessage = EMAIL_REMOTE_DOES_EXIST_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [JsonProperty(EMAIL_JSON_PROPERTY_NAME)]
    public String Email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = USERNAME_DISPLAY_NAME)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = USERNAME_REQUIRED_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [StringLength(USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH, MinimumLength = USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH, ErrorMessage = USERNAME_LENGTH_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [RegularExpression(USERNAME_REGEX, ErrorMessage = USERNAME_REGEX_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [Remote(USERNAME_REMOTE_DOES_EXIST_ACTION_NAME, USERNAME_REMOTE_EXIST_CONTROLLER_NAME, ErrorMessage = USERNAME_REMOTE_DOES_EXIST_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [JsonProperty(USERNAME_JSON_PROPERTY_NAME)]
    public String Username { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = PASSWORD_DISPLAY_NAME)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = PASSWORD_REQUIRED_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [StringLength(PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH, MinimumLength = PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH, ErrorMessage = PASSWORD_LENGTH_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [RegularExpression(PASSWORD_REGEX,ErrorMessage = PASSWORD_REGEX_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [JsonProperty(PASSWORD_JSON_PROPERTY_NAME)]
    public String Password { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = FIRST_NAME_DISPLAY_NAME)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = FIRST_NAME_REQUIRED_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [StringLength(FIRST_NAME_MAX_LENGTH, MinimumLength = FIRST_NAME_MIN_LENGTH, ErrorMessage = FIRST_NAME_LENGTH_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [RegularExpression(FIRST_NAME_REGEX, ErrorMessage = FIRST_NAME_REGEX_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [JsonProperty(FIRST_NAME_JSON_PROPERTY_NAME)]
    public String First_Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = LAST_NAME_DISPLAY_NAME)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = LAST_NAME_REQUIRED_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [StringLength(LAST_NAME_MAX_LENGTH, MinimumLength = LAST_NAME_MIN_LENGTH, ErrorMessage = LAST_NAME_LENGTH_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [RegularExpression(LAST_NAME_REGEX, ErrorMessage = LAST_NAME_REGEX_ERROR_MESSAGE)]
    [JsonProperty(LAST_NAME_JSON_PROPERTY_NAME)]
    public String Last_Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PROFILE_PICTURE_JSON_PROPERTY_NAME)]
    public String Profile_Picture { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(REGISTERATION_TIME_JSON_PROPERTY_NAME)]
    public long? RegisterationTime { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(VERIFIED_JSON_PROPERTY_NAME)]
    public int? Verified { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(INACCESSIBLE_JSON_PROPERTY_NAME)]
    public int? Inaccessible { get; set; }
}
```

#### Update#1

Here are some possible duplicates : 
[stackoverflow.com/questions/49701038](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701038) 
[stackoverflow.com/questions/14663763](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663763) 
It seems to be tiresome for nothing moreover it looks like an expensive operation to do on each signup, doesn't it ?

Comment: hmm i thought about using inhertiance but that does not work apperently; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520035/inheritance-of-custom-attributes-on-abstract-properties

Comment: It should work well but as i said i need properties to be as few as possible because i am sending the serialized json in api call. for example I put the six properties mentioned in the FormModel in a base class what if i need only two ?

Comment: Are you _assuming_ that the extra properties will be a problem or do you have a demonstrated performance problem with 2-3 properties that you don't need for a particular form? I get the sense that you're solving an imagined problem by creating an actual one.

Comment: @DStanley not a performance issue the thing is i am bound to some asymmetric encryption system with saved keys that allows limited amount of data to be encrypted .. so sadly the overhead in the serialized json will cause problems. moreover this is just a demo code the User Class is actually a lot bigger than this

Answer (score 1):

You might use AutoMapper for mapping from `User` to `SignUpFormModel`.

AutoMapper is useful when you need to map from model classes (or entities of a database model) to DTO objects used in API calls and in the opposite direction.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<User, SignUpFormModel>();
});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var user = new User() { First_Name = "tester" };
var formModel = mapper.Map<User, SignUpFormModel>(user);
```

[AutoMapper Getting Started Guide](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-started.html)

Update:

if the property name does not match in source and destination class, a custom mapping can be created for it, for example:

```
cfg.CreateMap<SignUpFormModel, User>()
    .ForMember(x => x.EmailInDestination, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.EmailInSource))
```

Comment: I am not familiar with this library. Do you in this code map values between similar properties? as I am noticing you are instantiating an user object filling its First_Name ..
I am not sure it clone the similar properties names

Comment: AutoMapper maps properties that have the same property name by default, it also by default supports flattening (https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html). It supports also configuration of custom mapping of properties. In case of your model the default mapping could be used, because all the properties in the form model have the same names as in the user class.

Comment: this will probably work but i think i need to do this at runtime as i using the FormModel as  a wrapper in asp.net mvc form 
@Models.FormModels.SignUpFormModel in the begining of the form.
as i see the resultant mapped object in the last line of your code . it gives a mapped instance but what i want is copying attributes and stick it the actual class definition to use it in this line  `@Models.FormModels.SignUpFormModel` in the begining of the form.

Comment: This is what i meant .. i am still trying to make a sense of it though.
[https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-copy-attribute-from-one-property-to-another](https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-copy-attribute-from-one-property-to-another)

Comment: it looks there are various ways how mpping can be done :) updated the answer, now it shows example of custom mapping of property, now i understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

The only way i could think of is by fetching the properties at runtime with reflection, and then applying that to the other class(es).

see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/accessing-attributes-by-using-reflection

and setting attributes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.addattributes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_ComponentModel_TypeDescriptor_AddAttributes_System_Object_System_Attribute___

Downsides:
- reflection is slow
- not really type safe

I'm not really a fan of this approach but i personally do not see another way. I think you should instead try to revise your architecture maybe so you can work around this problem.

Comment: so you mean I have to devise my own attribute that takes the given property in the parameters and accesses its attributes using reflection then assigning them to given member ? seems hard for a novice like me .. i actually though about using a base class but as i told sometimes i wont need all the properties in that base class leaving some size overhead in the serialized json

Comment: @MinaGerges first of all, not a fan of this approach either. Perhaps just go with the baseclass, i doubt the size overhead will be much of a problem.

Comment: it will because i am bound to some asymmetric encryption system with saved keys that encrypts limited amount of data .. so sadly the overhead will cause problems